# how to add index to the character vector in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

My original data is in a data.frame with 311 rows and 1 column. The data in the row is a url link. I am writing a for loop to extract one section of the url link

```
new_data_git <- data.frame(readLines("new_data.txt", skip = 0)); 

colnames(new_data_git) <- "url_link_new_git"

new_data_git$url_link_zip <- paste0(new_data_git$url_link_new_git,"/archive/master.zip");

for (i in 1:nrow(new_data_git)){

    split_file = strsplit(new_data_git$url_link_zip[i], split = "/", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
    name_of_saved_projs_zip = paste0(split_file[length(split_file)-3 +1], ".zip")
    print(name_of_saved_projs_zip)
}
```

My output is:

[1] "abc.zip"

[1] "def.zip"

[1] "gef.zip"

[1] "hdgadg.zip"

[1] "model.zip"

[1] "delays.zip"

[1] "recipe.zip"

[1] "food.zip"

[1] "Recipe.zip"

But when I try to print name_of_saved_projs_zip outside the for loop I only get the last value. And I m not sure how to refer the index to name_of_saved_projs_zip.
Unable to post the code in the code format on stack, hence have spaced out every line here.
Can someone please tell me what is wrong in my for loop and how can I see the right index for name_of_saved_projs_zip within and outside the loop. The index is crucial for a following loop function I need to write. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: `append` to `env` or `list2env` (not sure about the exact names of these functions). You are looping but not saving.

Comment: I thought I am saving it in the variable name_of_saved_projs_zip? Also, how do i get the right index? instead of all the 1's, it should be 1,2,3,4 and so on...

Comment: **Before** the loop: `name_of_saved_projs_zip <- character(nrow(new_data_git))`, last instruction of the loop: `name_of_saved_projs_zip[i] <- paste(etc)`. And remove the `print`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rui Barradas mentioned, need to add the following before the for loop

```
name_of_saved_projs_zip <- 1: nrow(new_data_git)
```

and in the for loop,

```
name_of_saved_projs_zip[i] <- paste(split_file[length(split_file)-3 +1], ".zip")
```

That did the trick !